# Difference between expected and predicted value

Tags: regression, prediction, expected-value

What is the difference between expected and predicted value? (predicted value tag is missing.)

---

[Here is the link](https://books.google.com/books?id=EzLffJlYISEC&pg=PA19&dq=predicted%20and%20expected%20value&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDg-XQubHMAhXjtYMKHWGaCZgQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=predicted%20and%20expected%20value&f=false) to a reference that defined the difference between expected value and predicted value. My understanding is that expected value is the value that the predicted variable takes at each covariate predicted value. However, the predicted value is the value of the dependent variable at the covariate mean. Please let me know if I understand this well.

Comment: Could you give some context perhaps, for instance with a specific model you're interested in?

Comment: Your comment indicates you distinguish between a "prediction" and a "predicted value".  What is that distinction?